# Cast DATETIME to STRING working on ARRAY of STRUCT on BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

in my table I have an attribute called 'messages' with this exact data type:

```
ARRAY<STRUCT<created_time  DATETIME ,`from` STRUCT<id STRING, 
name STRING,email STRING>, id STRING, message STRING>>
```

and I have defined a UDF named my_func()

Because UDF function in Big Query don't support the type DATETIME I need to cast the attribute  created_time.

So I tried this:

```
safe_cast ( messages as ARRAY<STRUCT<created_time  STRING ,
'from` STRUCT<id STRING, name STRING, email STRING>,
id STRING, message STRING>>) as messages_casted
```

and I get this error

```
Casting between arrays with incompatible element types is not
supported: Invalid cast from...
```

There is an error in the way I cast an array struct?

There is some way to use UDF with this data structure or the only way is to flatten the array and do the cast?

My goal is to take the array in the JS execution environment in order to make the aggregation with JS code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with JavaScript UDFs, you don't need to specify complex input data types explicitly. Instead, you can use the [`TO_JSON_STRING` function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#to_json_string). In your case, you can have the UDF take `messages` as a `STRING`, then parse it inside the UDF. You would call `my_func(TO_JSON_STRING(messages))`, for example.

Here is an example [from the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions):

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION SumFieldsNamedFoo(json_row STRING)
  RETURNS FLOAT64
  LANGUAGE js AS """
function SumFoo(obj) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var field in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(field) && obj[field] != null) {
      if (typeof obj[field] == "object") {
        sum += SumFoo(obj[field]);
      } else if (field == "foo") {
        sum += obj[field];
      }
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
var row = JSON.parse(json_row);
return SumFoo(row);
""";

WITH Input AS (
  SELECT STRUCT(1 AS foo, 2 AS bar, STRUCT('foo' AS x, 3.14 AS foo) AS baz) AS s, 10 AS foo UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, 4 AS foo UNION ALL
  SELECT STRUCT(NULL, 2 AS bar, STRUCT('fizz' AS x, 1.59 AS foo) AS baz) AS s, NULL AS foo
)
SELECT
  TO_JSON_STRING(t) AS json_row,
  SumFieldsNamedFoo(TO_JSON_STRING(t)) AS foo_sum
FROM Input AS t;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| json_row                                                            | foo_sum |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| {"s":{"foo":1,"bar":2,"baz":{"x":"foo","foo":3.14}},"foo":10}       | 14.14   |
| {"s":null,"foo":4}                                                  | 4       |
| {"s":{"foo":null,"bar":2,"baz":{"x":"fizz","foo":1.59}},"foo":null} | 1.59    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks to both, but the solution with TO_JSON_STRING I think is the one to rule them all !

Answer (score 1):

> Because UDF function in Big Query don't support the type DATETIME I need to cast the attribute created_time.

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and is a very simple way of Casting specific element of `ARRAY` leaving everything else as is.
So in below example - it `CAST`s created_time from `DATETIME` to `STRING` (you can use any compatible type you need in your case though)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT messages,
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE (SAFE_CAST(created_time AS STRING) AS created_time) 
    FROM UNNEST(messages) message
  ) casted_messages
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If you run it against your data - you will see original and casted messages - all elements should be same (value/type) with exception of (as expected) created_time which will be of casted type (STRING in this particular case) or NULL if not compatible

You can test / play with above using dummy data as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT [STRUCT<created_time  DATETIME, 
            `from` STRUCT<id STRING, name STRING, email STRING>, 
            id STRING, 
            message STRING>
      (DATETIME '2018-01-01 13:00:00', ('1', 'mike', 'zzz@ccc'), 'a', 'abc'),
      (DATETIME '2018-01-02 14:00:00', ('2', 'john', 'yyy@bbb'), 'b', 'xyz')
    ] messages
)
SELECT messages,
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE (SAFE_CAST(created_time AS STRING) AS created_time) 
    FROM UNNEST(messages) message
  ) casted_messages
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```